# javascript form handling multiple fields

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, error-handling

I have a form, echo'd from a php page, and I need to error handle multiple text fields

the 'phone' field is not meant to have more than 10 NUMBERS
the 'fname', 'oname' and 'sname' are meant to have only letters 
and the 'date' is meant to have only date format.
How do i achieve this using javascript?

```
echo '
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>Member Registration</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
        </head>

<!-- USE JAVASCRIPT FOR ERROR HANDLING -->
    <body>
        <h1>Member Registration</h1>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="register.php" name="regform" onsubmit="return validateForm();return allnumeric()">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="fname">First name: </label> <input class="fields" type="text" name="fname" value="" required></td>
                    <td><label for="sname">Surname: </label> <input class="fields" type="text" name="sname" value="" required></td>
                    <td><label for="oname">Other names: </label> <input class="fields" type="text" name="oname" value="" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Choose Profile Picture:</td><td> <input type="file" name="image" id="file" class="fields"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="nationalid" >National ID: </label> <input class="fields" type="text" name="nationalid" value="" required></td>
                    <td><label for="dob">Date: </label><input class="fields" type="text" name="dob" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="email">Email: </label> <input class="fields" type="text" name="email" value="" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="phone">Phone Number: </label> <input  class="fields" type="text" name="phone" value="" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="gender">Male</label><input type="radio" value="M" name="gender" required></td>
                    <td><label for="gender">Female</label><input type="radio" value="F" name="gender" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" onclick="return matchcheck"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>';
```

here is the script i have written so far

```
    function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["regform"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  }
}

function isNumeric(){
var a = document.getElementById('phone').value;
var b = /^\d+$/;

if(a.search(b) == -1)
{
alert(Must be Interger);
return false;
}
}


 </script>
```

Comment: where is your `validateForm()` JS code?

Comment: I only have validation for email.

Comment: and have added it onto the question